# Parameterized autocompletion in JS

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I'm looking for a way to implement parameterized autocompletion, similar to what Gerrit uses (see images below). The idea is to be able to make your own queries from the search bar, so that searching for `status:open owner:self` would result in the following solr query parameters: `q=+status:open+owner:self`.

[image]

[image]

I tried [complete.ly](http://complete-ly.appspot.com/), but like the other frameworks I have looked at, it seems to only support single predefined autocompletes (even though they may look like multiple ones). When the text is fully matched with one of the suggested queries, no more suggestions will come up. Is there a framework that supports this?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete then have it trigger for a new autocomplete when you press the spacebar, or other preferred key,